# iOS 8 Maps App replica

Tags: ios, mapkit

According to Apple MapKit view [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mapkit/reference/mkmapview_class/index.html) "...An MKMapView object provides an embeddable map interface, **similar to** the one provided by the **Maps application**..."

Here is screenshot of **Maps application**

[image]

I was digging through MapKit but can't find how to replicate this presentation.
Or it's not an MKMapView on the screenshot?

**Update**

Sure, I'm talking about globe view only.

Comment: Are you trying to get the Maps app UI (the buttons and such)? Or the globe view?

Comment: I want to replicate globe view

Comment: `MKMapView` provides the street layout and satellite views. I don't believe that you can get a Google Earth-style view using it.

Comment: @SevenBits but it's not Google Earth screenshot. It's Apple Maps app :-)

Answer (score 1):

The 3D globe view in Maps.app is not yet available in MapKit. You only get 2D and 3D tilted but flat maps.