# Map SDK with North Pole

Tags: ios, google-maps, maps, mapbox

Is there any Map SDK I can use specifically for iOS than can show me the North Pole kinda like in a globe manner rather than a flat map like Google Maps?

I need to show the North Pole like this to the user:
[image]

And not like this which is typically what other Map SDKs are which is flat:
[image]

Reason I need this is because I need to plot points that goes around the north pole or Arctic ocean. Problem with using a flat map is it doesn't actually show it properly. Say for example from one point to another in the Arctic Ocean, the line would be plotted from South-West and would continue to North-East line.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no public map API that fits your needs for presenting it in a globe manner like Google Earth. There are unfortunately always cartesian.

Apple seems to have it not implemented in MapKit for iOS 8: [iOS 8 Maps App replica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137109/ios-8-maps-app-replica)

I think they didn't changed that in iOS 9.

MapBox Earth looked like a good API but it's deprecated now: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-earth